# Multiple threads Atomic for IO expander driver

Tags: c, atomic

I am developing IO expander driver for Cortex-M arch and was wondering if combination of `_Atomic` and *interrupt disabling* is a MUST have to ensure data coherency and full atomicity, or is just `_Atomic` enough.

```c
//Simple driver implementation
struct driver {
    _Atomic uint8_t data_out; //Data to write
    _Atomic uint8_t write_data; //Flag indicating a need to write data
};
```

Idea is to only write if there is a change in data out. There are `3` helper functions to set, reset or toggle bits and one thread, that checks for changes and updates external device via *I2C*.

```c
#define pcf8574_outputs_set(_pcf_, _bits_)                                                                             \
    do {                                                                                                               \
        uint8_t val = atomic_load(&(_pcf_)->data_out);                                                                 \
        uint8_t new_val = val | ((uint8_t)(_bits_));                                                                   \
        if (new_val != val) {                                                                                          \
            atomic_store(&(_pcf_)->data_out, new_val);                                                \
            atomic_store(&(_pcf_)->write_data, 1);                                                                     \
        }                                                                                                              \
    } while (0)


#define pcf8574_outputs_reset(_pcf_, _bits_)                                                                           \
    do {                                                                                                               \
        uint8_t val = atomic_load(&(_pcf_)->data_out);                                                                 \
        uint8_t new_val = val & ((uint8_t) ~(_bits_));                                                                 \
        if (new_val != val) {                                                                                          \
            atomic_store(&(_pcf_)->data_out, new_val);                                             \
            atomic_store(&(_pcf_)->write_data, 1);                                                                     \
        }                                                                                                              \
    } while (0)


#define pcf8574_outputs_toggle(_pcf_, _bits_)                                                                          \
    do {                                                                                                               \
        atomic_fetch_xor(&(_pcf_)->data_out, (_bits_));                                                                \
        atomic_store(&(_pcf_)->write_data, 1);                                                                         \
    } while (0)
```

Finally, thread that updates value:

```c
void update(struct driver* pfc) {
    if (atomic_load(&pfc->write_data)) {
        atomic_store(&pfc->write_data, 0);
        do_i2c_write(atomic_load(&pfc->data_out);
    }
}
```

The ordering is seqcst, so I normally should not be worried that `write_data` gets written before new data is loaded.

Still, question remains, do I need to disable interrupts between first atomic load and last atomic store? For instance:

```c
#define pcf8574_outputs_set(_pcf_, _bits_)                                                                             \
    do {        
        irq_lock();\                                                                                                        \
        uint8_t val = atomic_load(&(_pcf_)->data_out);                                                                 \
        uint8_t new_val = val | ((uint8_t)(_bits_));                                                                   \
        if (new_val != val) {                                                                                          \
            atomic_store(&(_pcf_)->data_out, new_val);                                                \
            atomic_store(&(_pcf_)->write_data, 1);                                                                     \
        } 
        irq_restore();\                                                                                                             \
    } while (0)
```

Comment: Why ugly macros instead of functions? You should implement the data sharing privately encapsulated, `static` file scope variables are likely more convenient. As for atomicity, it is just helpful for guaranteeing that a single access won't get distrurbed. If you read, make descisions, then write, then that may or may not be interrupt safe, depending on what the interrupt updates. And also depending on if "the most recent update got delayed until next interrupt cycle" is acceptable or considered a real-time related bug. (Might apply in case of ADC or PWM but maybe not here.)

Comment: *If you read, make descisions, then write, then that may or may not be interrupt safe, depending on what the interrupt updates* It is a multi-threading environment. Normally in cooperative mode, context switch will happen on task delay,mutex-wait,..., but this is not guaranteed to really be always the case, unlike in preemptive move, when it can switch out at any time.

I agree macros are ugly, tho.

Comment: Context switches between processes/threads can't really be compared with interrupts, since the latter could have much harder real-time requirements. Toggling the specific interrupt flag on/off is one way to solve the problem. Toggling the global interrupt mask is pretty much always wrong.

Comment: *Toggling the global interrupt mask is pretty much always wrong.* Why?

Comment: Because it disrupts interrupts in completely non-related parts of the program, creating "hard coupling" between unrelated parts and generally messing things up. Drivers toggling the global mask are therefore broken and not suitable to be used together with other code. About the only time when you should ever touch this mask is: when enabling all interrupts in the beginning of the program, and perhaps when doing very sensitive stuff like on-chip flash/eeprom programming and can't allow _any_ interrupt during that time.

Comment: Learnt something new. Do you have a good article on that to provide some evidence of * it disrupts interrupts in completely non-related parts of the program, creating "hard coupling" between unrelated parts and generally messing things up*? What is messed up for very short interrupt lock?

Comment: This isn't the place to discuss it and this comes from personal experience, having worked with embedded systems program design & trouble-shooting for the past 20 years. On several occasions, this has been found out to be a severe bug in various systems, on a case-to-case basis.